# Migrating from RepositoryRestResource to Controller + Repository

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I had a simple REST repository, annotated with `@RepositoryRestResource`. This worked fine, and exposed my MongoDB collection as a REST resource. However, I want to reuse the Repository in a different project without using it as a REST resource, and I'd also not like to have those dependencies in that project.

So, from one project I migrated to 3 projects:

- The repository project (1 repository, and 1 domain object)
- UI Project 1
- UI Project 2

UI Project 1 and 2 both depend on the repository project. But now I have some troubles migrating. I had a nice HATEOAS REST webservice, and I'd like to keep that. For it seems for that to work, I have to let my domain object extend `ResourceSupport`. I don't want that, because it's in a project without support for REST.

So, my question is: how do I create a controller in UI Project 1 which will still provide full REST and full HATEOAS support without letting my repository project depend on REST support?

Comment: Annotation are just annotation/metadata... If you don't include spring-data-rest your repository should still work as a regular repository but not exposed as endpoint... Make the `spring-date-rest` one optional. If you don't want this your objects don't have nor should extend `ResourceSupport` your domain objects should not be exposed you should create a DTO that extends ResourceSupport`.

Comment: The annotations are imported as a dependency. If I don't include the dependency, how can I compile the code? My current solution is to have the repository in the repository project, and extend the interface in the UI project and have it annotated there. Not sure if it's the best solution, but it works.

Comment: Why are you even compiling... Why aren't they including a dependency jar... That latter is reuse, the first is copy paste... The repository project should deliver a `repository.jar` and the others should have a dependency on that. They shouldn't recompile the code... If you do it like that and make the rest thing optional it should work as annotations are metadata. So basically do the dependency in your repository project and make it optional.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create the links yourself as presented here https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas

Comment: Well, that won't work AFAIK, because then I need to extend ResourceSupport. Which is not possible, because the repository project shouldn't have a dependency on REST